# MinGW 4.7.1 doesn't recognize command line option -static-libstdc++

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, codeblocks

So I recently installed a new version of CodeBlocks with the MinGW 4.7.1 compiler, and I am no longer able to build my projects.  The compiler throws the following error:

```
error: unrecognized command line option '-static-libstdc++'
```

I believe I was previously using 4.4.1 (going by the files in MinGW/bin).  I installed the CobeBlocks 12.11 package that is supposed to come with the 4.7.1 compiler included.

How do I solve this?  Removing that option from the compiler settings causes my previously functional application to instantly crash upon startup.

Comment: I added that, and the same error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler bundled with Codeblocks 12.11 is tdm-gcc 4.7.1, which by default links libstdc++ statically and reports `-static-libstdc++` as an error. So if you want to dynamically link to libstdc++, add `-shared-libstdc++`.